# Рекомендуется и "позволительно" ли использовать дженерики таким образом?

Tags: typescript, архитектура, проектирование, typescript-типы

Возникла необходимость в указании для поля строго литерального типа из перечня, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать это для указания компилятору (для функции). И вот пока это выглядит как-то так:

**Общий тип:**

```
type NameType = 'John' | 'Stepan';
```

**Объект документов:**

```
const documents = {
    'John': {
        'cardId': 12
    },
    'Stepan': {
        'hasPass': true
    }
} satisfies Record<NameType, Object>;
```

**Классы:**

```
abstract class Person<T extends NameType>{
    public readonly name: T;

    constructor(name: T){
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected _getDocument<K extends keyof typeof documents[T]>(document: K): typeof documents[T][K]{
        return documents[this.name][document];
    }
}

class John extends Person<'John'>{
    constructor(){
        super('John');
    }
}

class Stepan extends Person<'Stepan'>{
    constructor(){
        super('Stepan');
    }
}
```

И тут вопрос - позволительно ли так использовать дженерики? Вроде как они обычно используются не для указания типа всего-то одного поля, а как например в случае с классом Stack - где от указанного типа зависит то, какие элементы будут.

Возможно есть ещё какое-то другое решение, где не придётся подобным образом использовать дженерики? И да, сделать абстрактным поле name в классе Person нельзя, т.к. с ним планируются операции внутри конструктора.

Comment: Для начала напрашивается вопрос — а зачем это всё? Почему у Джона не должно быть `hasPass: false`, а у Степана не должно быть `cardId: null` например, чтобы всё было по-человечески?

Comment: Это лишь пример. Суть в том, что разные объекты с разными элементами

Comment: Но вопрос «а зачем» от этого никуда не девается, и он необходим для ответа на вопрос «позволительно ли»

Comment: И зачем хранить документы в отдельной глобальной переменной, а не напрямую в Person, тоже максимально неочевидно. Пока что для меня это выглядит как переусложнение ради переусложнения

Comment: Документы одни на каждую группу (к примеру, на все экземпляры класса John документы с cardId с одинаковым значением) поэтому на каждый класс поле документов и не создаётся. При этом с их использованием будут происходить сторонние действия вне класса

Comment: Это лишь пример, демонстрирующий саму ситуацию (в случае с документами, как имя использоваться будет для типизации). Вопрос можно было бы ограничить лишь кодом с типом и классами без метода с документами, смысл лишь в таком применении дженериков